# is there a way to std::basic_istream::get with a basic_streambuf to also read the delimeter char?

Tags: c++20, fstream, stringbuffer

Given

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<stringstream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
  std::fstream  file("MyFile.txt", std::fstream::in);
  std::stringbuf sb;
  file.get(sb, '\0');
  file.get(); // (1) wasting the delimiter char
  
   return 0;
}
```

Basically, What I am looking for is to avoid doing the `(1)` statement as it looks just not tidy.

The (approximate) alternative workaround could be `getline`, but is not dynamically allocated like `stringbuf` as it requires a fixed size buffer, so it is not an equivalent solution in the case when using a `std::basic_streambuf`.

is there a way with `std::basic_istream::get(basic_streambuf&, ...)` to also read the delimiter char without forcing to the next statement to do a wasted `.get`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAIi am pointing out of `getline` already in the question, but doesn't fit the use case.

Comment: eventually there is a `seekg(1, fstream::cur)` rather than do a wasted get.

Comment: There are two different functions named `getline`. "not dynamically allocated like stringbuf as it requires a fixed size buffer" is about one of them.

Comment: thanks. i missed that. much appreciated.